# Per User Authentication for External Service

Tags: apex, integration, apexrest, oauth, namedcredentials

As part of my use case, I need to integrate different external sources from Salesforce . All the authentication has to be per-user and this whole thing needs to be part of managed package. Now the few ways which could think of on top of my mind:-

1. Use Named Credential and user would need to navigate to Authentication Settings for External Systems
   (Problem - Extra Click , User Training)
2. Use Custom Auth. Provider and fetch the access token through authProviderPlugin and store the access token in customSetting /CustomMetadata for each user.
   (Problem - Less Secure)

Is there any other way or what is the best suggested way to approach this problem ?

Comment: You have the right options. The auth provider framework grabs and "stores" the token for you - no custom setting / metadata is needed.